# How to configure InternalResourceViewResolver amd/or @Controller bean to deliver static resources?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, static-resource

I have created simple HelloWorld project from Spring MVC template in Spring STS.

I found that there is a HomeController bean, which decides, which JSP to call and prepares information for it. As I see, this class associates HTTP request with it's method.

So, now I need to have some images or javascript files to be loaded into my page. But HomeController in template configuration does not allow this.

What is the simplest way to provide browser access to some folder on the server? What if I remove HomeController at all, will DefaultServlet come in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

Where

- `mapping` is the URL at which the resources will be accessible: `/static/main.css`
- `location` is the webapp-root relative location of the files.

You can have more than one `<mvc:resources>` tags. [See here for more infomration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

Comment: Thanks! And where to put this tag? If I put it into `servlet-context.xml` I get "The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:resources" is not bound." message from Eclipse.

Comment: You need to add the mvc: namespace. The documentation I linked contains it

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was defined by default, but just without `mvc` prefix.